# VS2010 Intellitrace, can you actually get the debugger to rewind?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've just installed Intellitrace, and it seems that it only collects data from previous points during debugging, and I haven't found a way to get the debugger to step back to previous execution points using intellitrace.

Is this possible because this is what is implied in the marketing material I read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the developers [blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ianhu/intellitrace-what-we-collect):

When customers first hear about IntelliTrace what is usually conjured to mind is the ability to step backward though their code, checking to see what happened previously with all the full features and information of normal live debugging. It would be wonderful if we could fully deliver on that vision with IntelliTrace but the restrictions of both keeping program execution time overhead and log file size down while still providing useful information prevent that. If your vision of IntelliTrace was collecting the whole world of data and being able to step back though it then the section below might be a bit of a disappointment. But we feel that the choices made really have given the best balance between speed and size of use and collection of valuable data for just about all users.

Answer (score 2):

Caveat emptor: This is shameless self-promotion, but I think it's pretty on topic.

You may want to have a peek at [Rec Debugger](http://recdebugger.com). It's supposed to do what you're asking for - let you step backwards in .NET programs. It is in beta, however, and it throws NotImplementedExceptions all over the place. Also, it's not nearly as fast as I would want it to be. But I would very much appreciate bug-reports so that I can concentrate my efforts on the most easily encountered problems.

Again, I'm affiliated with the site I suggested. I stumbled upon this question when I was doing some google searches, and I have no intention of continuing to spam my site here. (But feel free to vote down if this is considered inappropriate)

Comment: The site doesn't exist and the extension doesn't install on VS 2015. Looks like you abandoned this effort.